# CKEditor 4 Control couldn't get cursor focus on toolbar buttons while using keyboard tab key, requirement for 508 Accessibility feature

Tags: accessibility, section508, ckeditor4

I am using CKEditor Standard Package Version 4.16.1/4.16.2, I am trying to make this CKEditor control as 508 Accessibility feature.
In order to be compliant with 508 standards CKEditor must be accessible by keyboard. So we need to be able to use the TAB button using keyboard to navigate through CKEditor's toolbar buttons.
Currently we couldn't get cursor focus on any of the CKEditor's toolbar buttons by using keyboard tab key.
If the cursor is in the input for Display Sequence and you press TAB the CKEditor's toolbar buttons will be skipped and the cursor focus will go straight to the text area of the CKEditor control. We want to make this CKEditor control and CKEditor's toolbar buttons as 508 accessibility standards compliant.
Please let me know if there is any easy to achieve this or if we need to make any config changes or code changes in order to make this CKEditor as 508 accessibility standards compliant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to press Alt+F10

[Accessibility Support in CKEditor 4](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_a11y.html#:%7E:text=Keyboard%20Navigation,-Once%20the%20editor&text=Alt%2BF10%20%E2%80%93%20Moves%20the%20focus%20to%20the%20toolbar.)